# ext.js combobox no values

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I`m trying to define a combobox in ext.js with static values, but the displayed combobox, doens't show anything but 3 empty oprions.

here's the code:

```
xtype:"combo",
id: "user_flag",
fieldLabel: "Status",
labelStyle: "width:100px",
store: new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
            fields: ["value", "name"],
            data: [
                  ["-1","Banned"], ["0", "Inactive"], ["1", "Active"]
                  ]
            }),
disaplayField: "name",
valueField: "value",
selectOnFocus: true,
mode: 'local',
editable: false,
triggerAction: "all"
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please follow the example of the next link

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox

```
    // The data store containing the list of states
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data : [
        {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
        {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
        {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
        //...
    ]
});

// Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
xtype:"combo",
id: "user_flag",
fieldLabel: "Status",
labelStyle: "width:100px",
store: new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
            fields: ["value", "name"],
            data: [
                  ["value":"-1","name":"Banned"], ["value":"0","name":"Inactive"], ["value":"1", "name":"Active"]
              ]
            }),
disaplayField: "name",
valueField: "value",
selectOnFocus: true,
mode: 'local',
editable: false,
triggerAction: "all"
```